# How to execute query on csv file

Tags: c#-4.0

i have uploaded a csv file and also make a data-table from csv file.now i want to find distinct values from each columns of data-table.what will be the code for this.
i have tried by this code but there is error show that object is not ADODB.what is ADODB and how can i remove this error

```
   public static DataTable GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(string csv_file_path)
{
 DataTable csvData = new DataTable();
try
 {
     using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path))
     {
        csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
        csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
        //read column names
        string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();
        foreach (string column in colFields)
        {
           DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column);
           datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
           csvData.Columns.Add(datecolumn);
        }
        while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
        {
           string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
           //Making empty value as null
           for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
           {
              if (fieldData[i] == "")
              {
                 fieldData[i] = null;
              }
           }
           csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
        }
  foreach (DataColumn col in csvdata.Columns)
            {

                foreach (DataRow ro in csvdata.Rows)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = "" + ro[col];

                }

            }
     }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
```

}

Comment: This is not a platform for delegating your programming tasks.

Comment: Code it yourself, and in case of questions during that process, ask here.

Comment: now check it this code an error

Comment: Give a check here https://superuser.com/questions/7169/querying-a-csv-file